# How fund the distance of the two line

Tags: geometry

Can you tell the follow questions: how to find a dictance for the given two line l_1: 13x-y+6z+6=0; l_2: 26x-2y+12z-4=0

Comment: i think you meant These two planes,

Comment: It is easy to see those two planes are parallel, There are many possibilities to calculate distance, if you do not want to understand, there exist a simple formula.

Comment: do you know the Hessian normal form?

Comment: Can you tell me how to proced, yes i did that the given plane is parallel, but i didn't know how to find te distance for the given plane

Comment: Choose any point on one plane and construct perpendicular line, find intersection and calculate distance (there are a couple of other methods).

Comment: Tell me please in your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Vector $\vec v=(13,-1,6)$ is perpendicular to both planes and its length is $v=\sqrt{206}$.

2) Choose two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ one for each plane, for instance: $P_1=(0,6,0)$ and $P_2=(0,-2,0)$, and set $\vec w=P_1-P_2$.

3) The distance between planes is given by $|(\vec v\cdot\vec w)/v|$.

Comment: 2) i didn't know how to proced

Comment: You must find $(x,y,z)$ which obey the given plane equation, see my edited answer.

Comment: Guess a point ... to be "simple", it is easy here, two coordinates could be set to zero.